# Should I use CFPlugin or dlopen() for plugin for C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, plugins

I need to make a plugin library on OSX which shall be loaded at run time. The library is mostly in C++. The way plugin needs to behave is that the program will scan a directory and search for plugins. Now it needs to get some information from plugins (like type) and needs to create instance based on that.

I searched for options and got these two for OSX - `dlopen()` and `CFPlugin`. The advantage with `dlopen()` is that we don't need to extend our base abstract class (which we have to if we use `CFPlugin`). The disadvantage is that we need to load the library before knowing its type.

With `CFPlugin`, Apple has not clearly mentioned that is it loaded before we create its instance or not. We can call `CFPlugInFindFactoriesForPlugInTypeInPlugIn` function to know all the functions capable of creating instance. But is the plugin loaded before it searches for available functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally going ahead with `dlopen()` to load the `*.bundle` plugin. Advantage of using bundle is that `*.plist` shall always be embedded in it and any information we need before loading the bundle can be obtained from the `plist` file.